# Skip function decorator of the parent class function when called from child class

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7

Say, I have two classes `A` and `B`. When the `test()` function is called from the child `class B` using `super`, it should skip the `@validate` decorator. How can I force the `super` method to skip the decorator of the parent class function when called from the child class? Is there any possibility?

```
class A:

   @validate  
   def test():
      pass

Class B(A):

   @validate 
   def test():
      super(B, self).test()
      pass
```

Comment: Is it necessary to apply `validate` decorator to function `test` in class `B`?

Comment: @Poolka Yes it is necessary

Comment: However those functions are very different - `A.test` does some work while `B.test` just calls another function to do the work. So it seems reasonable to have `B.test` without this very decorator. I guess you may move it inside `B.test` and apply to the code where `validate` is really needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `@validate` annotation in the parent class, so it won't be called

```
class A:

   def test():
      pass

Class B(A):

   @validate 
   def test()
      super(B, self).test()
      pass
```

Another option is to have an intermediate method

```
class A:

   @validate  
   def test():
      intermediate()

   def intermediate():
       pass


Class B(A):

   @validate 
   def test()
      super(B, self).intermediate()
      pass
```

Comment: I can't remove @validate in parent function as there are many use cases in many parts of the project.